# Why is my HPC job hanging until time limit then cancelled

Tags: slurm, hpc

I have a script which runs 4 jobs, the first one with no dependency and the subsequent 3 each dependent on the preceding one. The first 3 jobs run successfully. The third one runs successfully but hangs after completing the computation until it is cancelled when it reaches the time limit. subsequently the 4th job does not run due to unmet dependency.
Below is the slurm scheduling of the four jobs

```
#!/bin/bash
#commands running on login node, including definition of environment variables

#scheduling
echo "Running WPS ..., no dependency"
jobid1=$(sbatch  --parsable ${RUNSCRIPTSDIR}/wps.sh)

echo "Running real ..."
jobid2=$(sbatch --parsable --dependency=afterok:$jobid1 ${RUNSCRIPTSDIR}/real.sh)

echo "Running WRF ..."
jobid3=$(sbatch --parsable --dependency=afterok:$jobid2 ${RUNSCRIPTSDIR}/wrf.sh)

echo "Running UPP ..."
jobid4=$(sbatch --parsable --dependency=afterok:$jobid3 ${RUNSCRIPTSDIR}/upp.sh)
```

In the above scheduled jobs, wps, real and wrf run. wrf.sh takes about 45 min. If I put --time=1:00:00, wrf will finish at about 45min, then squeue shows it is running until 1 hour, then wrf_job.err will show

```
srun: Job step aborted: Waiting up to 32 seconds for job step to finish.
slurmstepd: error: *** JOB 1076 ON lms200com01 CANCELLED AT 2023-09-06T17:33:59 DUE TO TIME LIMIT ***
slurmstepd: error: *** STEP 1076.0 ON lms200com01 CANCELLED AT 2023-09-06T17:33:59 DUE TO TIME LIMIT ***
```

All computations are successfully completed by wrf.sh, in fact at the end there is

```
d01 2023-09-07_00:00:00 wrf: SUCCESS COMPLETE WRF
```

Below are the slurm directives in wrf.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --ntasks=216
#SBATCH --job-name=wrf_job
#SBATCH --output=wrf_job.out
#SBATCH --error=wrf_job.err
#SBATCH --mail-user=zmumba@gmail.com
#SBATCH --mail-type=ALL
#SBATCH --time=00:45:00

#some commands
echo "Starting wrf_noda"
#Dates calculation
export year=$(date "+%Y")
export month=$(date "+%m")
export day=$(date "+%d")
export hour="00"

echo "starting wrf run"
mpirun ./wrf.exe
echo "Done running WRF"
```

starting wrf run is printed
mpirun ./wrf.exe runs to completion
Done running WRF is never printed

Any assistance will be appreciated.